# Как расширить функционал opensource браузера?

Tags: c++, firefox, opensource, браузер, chromium

Необходимо собрать свой браузер на основе chromium или mozzila, поменяв название и лого, также этот браузер должен иметь некторые дополнительные функции.

Первостепенная задача состоит в парсинге нескольких сайтов и создания страницы с данными из них. То есть нажав на кнопку в браузере человек видит страницу со слиянием нескольких сайтов. Почитав документацию, понял, что вопрос можно решить с помощью Browser Extensions.

Появилась идея: написать свое расширение, а затем собрать браузер с ним, чтобы, когда пользователь устанавливал браузер у него уже все работало, как я задумал.

Но появилась проблема, оказывается, чтобы собрать так chromium можно прописать расширения в файле external_extensions.json, но это срабатывает только для Linux и Mac OS, а для Windows необходимо настраивать реестр (это называется внешнее расширение), а меня такой вариант не устраивает.

По поводу мозиллы не нашел вообще информации по сборке с расширениями по умолчанию. Буду рад, если подскажите.

Вопрос такой: с какой стороны подойти к расширению функционала браузера на уровне исходных кодов, есть ли возможность написать расширение функциональности не углубляясь сильно в архитектуру браузера, а написав расширение (может быть даже на языке c++) и собрать это все в единый браузер?

Очень нужен совет, с чего начать и где найти информацию по этому поводу (ссылки на документацию приветствуются).

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: *"Первостепенная задача состоит в парсинге нескольких сайтов и создания страницы с данными из них."* -- для этого не нужно собирать свой браузер. Посмотрите на [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

Comment: @jfs Спасибо за информацию, о таком инструменте не знал, будет полезно изучить, но проблема в том, что преподаватель требует отдельный браузер со своим логотипом и названием, то есть без сборки не обойтись.

Comment: особые требования указывайте прямо в вопросе. Добавьте все обязательные пункты, которые ваш преподаватель указал¶ В чём цель упражнения: поменять пару строк (название), картинок (лого) и пересобрать браузер и установщик? Или вы хотите приложение поверх браузера написать? К примеру, используя [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) или [qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/topics-web-content.html)

Comment: @jfs, уточнил вопрос. Преподавателю важно увидеть как бы "новый" продукт, не важно будет ли это переборка популярного браузера с заменой логотипа или написанное приложение на qt с отдельной логикой и расширением функционала браузера. Просто выбор пал на сборку, так как думал, что будет проще и быстрее. На просторах сети часто вижу любительские сборки мозиллы, куда люди в установщик включают расширения, которые ставятся вместе с браузером, но в документации, как это сделать, к сожалению, не нашел.